# SQL Distinct on different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, distinct

I have the following query

```
select t1.work_date, t1.proposal_job_ref, t1.timesheet_time, t2.proposal_title

from dbo.timesheet_entries t1
inner join dbo.proposal t2
    on t1.proposal_job_ref = t2.proposal_ref_code

inner join dbo.consultant t3
    on t3.consultant_id = t1.consultant_id

where t1.consultant_id = 2
and t1.work_date between '01/09/2013' and '30/09/2013'

order by t1.work_date
```

I'd like to remove records from this query that have the same value for the field **proposal_job_ref**

I tried adding **distinct** after the **select** however this doesn't work as I think it removes duplicate entries based on work_**date**

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
work date    proposal_ref_code    timesheet_time    proposal_title
01/09/2013   p11111               8                 Web App Development
02/09/2013   p22222               4                 Mobile Development
03/09/2013   p11111               6                 Web App Development
04/09/2013   p33333               8                 Database Design
```

Using the table above, once my query is executed I would like the 3rd row to be removed because it is has the same **proposal_ref_code** as the first row, ie, p11111.

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What should happen to the other column values that are not distinct?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The most efficient solution is likely to vary depending on your DBMS.

Comment: If you have multiple rows with the same `proposal_job_ref` but different values for `timesheet_time` or `work_date` or `proposal_title`, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: have you tried group by proposal_job_ref

Comment: And why remove that line and not the first?

Comment: Hi Folks, I have added some sample data, I hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: @juergend Whether the 1st record or 3rd record is removed does not matter, what matters is that no duplicated proposal_ref_code appear in the query results.

Comment: So you don't need the other columns at all? Why not only  select the `proposal_ref_code`

Comment: Who said I don't need the other columns? Of course I do, otherwise I wouldn't be retrieving them. I just want to perform a distinct on the column proposal_ref_code.

Comment: What would happen to rest of the data - will you select row 1 data or row 3 data on finding that **proposal_job_ref** field is same in both rows

Answer (score 1):

Please Try it, I hope it's useful to you

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY work_date ORDER BY work_date DESC) FROM tablename 
)
delete from CTE where RN>1
```

Comment: This should be partitioning by `proposal_ref_code`, not `work_date`. I also think the question is about selecting only one record, not deleting the records, so it would be `SELECT <columns> FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1`